# Returning 5 Most Recent Trips Per ID

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the number of trips taken and a station_id, and I want to return the 5 most recent trips made per ID (sample image of the table is below)

The query I made below aggregates the station id's and the most recent trip, but I am having a difficult time returning the 5 most recent

```
SELECT start_station_id, MAX(start_time) 
FROM `bpd.shop.trips` 
group by start_station_id, start_time
```

Trips:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPM7h.jpg

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY start_station_id ORDER BY start_time DESC) as seqnum
      FROM `bpd.shop.trips` t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Option 1

```
#standardSQL
SELECT record.*
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY start_time DESC LIMIT 5) arr
  FROM `bpd.shop.trips` t
  GROUP BY start_station_id
), UNNEST(arr) record
```

Option 2

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT (pos) FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(win) AS pos
  FROM `bpd.shop.trips`
  WINDOW win AS (PARTITION BY start_station_id ORDER BY start_time DESC)
) 
WHERE pos <= 5
```

I recommend using Option 1 as more scalable option